# How would I solve this equation $\dfrac{x−1}{(x+1)(3x−5)\sqrt{x+3}}=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I go about solving this equation? Would the $\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}$ reduce down to just $1$? The equation was $\dfrac{x−1}{(x+1)(3x−5)\sqrt{x+3}}=0$

Comment: See my edit, is that correct?

Comment: This equation is (almost) the same as $x-1=0$. Just check that for your solution $x$, the denominator is defined and not 0.

Comment: Numerator has to be $0$ and denominator should not be $0$ for the same values.

Comment: When I enter this equation into mathway.com I get x(sqrt(x+3)) - sqrt(x+3) = 0

Answer (score 4):

No, $x-1 \ne x+1$ hence it wouldn't reduce to $1$. Frankly, all you'll have to do is this:

$$\require{cancel} \dfrac{x−1}{(x+1)(3x−5)\sqrt{x+3}}=0 \\ x−1=\cancelto{0}{0\left((x+1)(3x−5)\sqrt{x+3}\right)} \\ \therefore x=1$$

That's the only solution. Double check the denominator and you'll see that it is indeed defined at $x=1$. That's what you need to do as far as *solving* it goes.